# Div-container around product-cards in php

Tags: php, webshop

I'm really new to php and now I got stucked on what I thought was something really easy. Byt I can't see wheres my problem is.

I'm trying to create a webshop page that displays all my products. 
To the problem! 
Here is my code so far. It displays all products as expected but it closes the main and product-container before all product-cards except from the first one. How to wrap all product-cards in the same div?

```
$pdo = connect();
$limit = 20;
$offset = 0;
$stmt = get_all_products($pdo, $limit, $offset);

$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>

    <main>
        <section class="product-container">
        <?php
    foreach($rows as $row) {
        ?>
        <div class="product-card">
            <img class="product-image" src="<?php echo $row['Img'];?>" >
            <h2 class="title"><?php echo $row['ProductName']; ?></h2>
            <span class="price"><?php echo $row['Price'];?></span><span>:-</span>
        </div>
        </section>
    </main>
    <?php

}?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move the closing `main` and `section` tag after the `foreach` loop is closed.

```
<main>
    <section class="product-container">
    <?php
    foreach($rows as $row) {
        ?>
        <div class="product-card">
            <img class="product-image" src="<?php echo $row['Img'];?>" >
            <h2 class="title"><?php echo $row['ProductName']; ?></h2>
            <span class="price"><?php echo $row['Price'];?></span><span>:-</span>
        </div>
    <?php }?> <!-- Close the foreach loop here -->
    </section>
</main>
```

Comment: Thank you!! It works perfect! So close but yet so far from the answer! :)